# Passing parameters to lambda in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, parameters, mutable

I seems to miss some point in lambda mechanism in C++.  Here is the code:

```
std::vector<int> vec (5);

int init = 0;
std::generate(begin(vec), end(vec), [init]() mutable { return ++init; });

for (auto item : vec) {
    std::cout << item << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl << init << std::endl;
```

If there is no `mutable` it wouldn't compile because I'm changing `init` in lambda.
Now, as I understand lambda is called for each vector's item with a **new fresh copy** of `init` which is 0.
So, 1 must be returned every time.
But the output of this piece of code is:
**1 2 3 4 5

0**

It looks like `generate` captures by copy `init` **only once** at the beginning of its execution.  But why? Is it supposed to work like this?

Comment: That's exactly how its supposed to work

Comment: You'd *probably* get what you are describing if you used a `for` loop and in the body of the loop you did something like `vec[i] = ([init] () mutable {return ++init;})();`, because this creates one lambda function every iteration.

Comment: @Bakuriu. That was my point of confusion - I thought that for loop and `generate(begin, end, lambda)` should do the same thing.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Now, as I understand lambda is called for each vector's item with a new fresh copy of init which is 0.

That is not correct.  A lambda is just a another way to make a class and provide an `operator()` for it.  The `[]` part of the lambda describes the member variables and whether they are captured by reference or value.  The `()` part of the lambda is the parameter list for the `operator()` and the `{}` part is the body of that function.  The `mutable` part tells the compiler to make the `operator()` non `const` as it is `const` by default.

So

```
[init]() mutable { return ++init; }
```

Becomes

```
struct compiler_generated_name
{
    int init; // we captured by value

    auto operator()() // since we used mutable this is non const
    {
        return ++init;
    }
};
```

<sup>I used a struct here for brevity of typing but a lambda is specified as a class type so `class` could be used.</sup>

This means the `init` is the same `init` from the last iteration as you only ever capture once.  This is important to remember as

```
auto generate_lambda()
{
    int foo = 0;
    return [&foo](){ return ++foo; };
}
```

Will leave you with a dangling reference to `foo` when the function returns and using it is undefined behavior.

Comment: This is the best/simplest explanation that I've seen for implementing lambda expressions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The lambda is a compiler-generated struct equivalent to:

```
struct lambda
{
    int init = 0; // captured value

    auto operator()() // non-const, due to `mutable`
    {
        return ++init;
    }
};
```

Therefore, `init` is captured and copied inside the lambda just once - calling the lambda multiple times will not capture `init` again.

Answer (score 5):

You are coping and seeing the initial value of init -- what you you probably want to do acording to what you expect is to capture `init` by reference.....

```
std::vector<int> vec (5);

int init = 0;
std::generate(begin(vec), end(vec), [&init]() mutable { return ++init; });

for (auto item : vec) {
    std::cout << item << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl << init << std::endl;
```

Comment: I used it many times with [&param] and know how it works. This is just an example code which I run after read about mutable applied to lambdas

Comment: How does this explain why an increasing list of values was generated and how does capturing by reference fix that?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Is it a test for me?))

Comment: @IgorStack No.  I am asking Soren as I don not understand what question he is trying to answer.

Comment: I was explaining why the last line of output was 0 -- somehow thought that was the question.

Comment: @Soren Ah okay.  I didn't see that part.

Comment: It's OK, my question wasn't "how to make all the values 1" or "how to make them sequential". But rather "why they are sequential while I expect them to be equal".

Comment: Note: The `mutable` keyword is not needed when the capture is by reference rather than by value.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is here "Now, as I understand lambda is called *for each vector's item* with a new fresh copy of init which is 0" (my italics). No; as you can see the lambda is completely separate, and therefore ignorant, of the vector code. The initialisation of `item` takes place each time the lambda form itself is evaluated (as opposed to each time the resulting value is called); here this means each time the function `generate` is called: just once.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = ([](int j)->int {return j; }, 3);
```